# Choose migration target other than suggested

Tags: support, migration

I feel kinda stupid, because it seems like this option is a basic one but I can't find it.

Is there a way to suggest a migration target for a question other than given options? It's about 5th time I have seen this (over a year, thus not so much but still).

My current example is this [Raspberry Pi High CPU Usage With Sense Hat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625880/raspberry-pi-high-cpu-usage-with-sense-hat)
Clearly best option is to move it to raspberry SE, though I see only:

> Close > Off-topic > migration:
>
> - belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com
> - belongs on superuser.com
> - belongs on tex.stackexchange.com
> - belongs on dba.stackexchange.com
> - belongs on stats.stackexchange.com

How can I flag it with appropriate suggestion? It would be nice to have free choice in this dialog.

*(please retag from support to feature request, if this is impossible)*

Comment: the targets are, IIRC, the top 5 (4+meta? 5+meta? not sure) sites where migrations are successful, so that is why the list is limited. As far as I understand it, opening all of them will never happen as too many wrong migrations would happen

Comment: The https://tex.stackexchange.com recommendation has always struck me as an odd recommendation. There are tons of StackExchange sites that must be far more common migration destinations. Of all the programming questions in all the different languages and different platforms, really how often is tex really the logical destination?!? I suspect a methodological error or historical anachronism for including tex in this list of sites. IMHO, the list of destinations should be dynamic, driven by textual (or, more simply) tags used in the question. Or just give us drop down/search of all the sites.

Comment: I.e., how often is https://tex.stackexchange.com the appropriate destination for a StackOverflow question that does not bear a `tex` (or `tex`-related) tag? It has to be close to zero.